# What is the capacity of an electron to absorb energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electrons, atomic-physics

When an electron get excited we find that electron absorbs energy and jumps to the required shell. This means that electron can absorb an infinite amount of energy and can get excited to infinity shell. If that is the case then what about photoelectric effect. It seems to me that the electron can never move out of the atom if there are infinity number of shells.

Comment: I doubt the infinite part. If it absorbs more energy than needed for pair forming....  Not a physics guy though.

Comment: It is entirely possible to an electron to stop being bound to a particular nucleus - to "escape". Why would an "infinite number of shells" stop this from being possible?

Comment: If that is the case then why electrons take energy and require any threshold energy to jump out from the atom??

Answer (score 7):

There are two separate issues here (not sure which of the two you mean):

The first problem is a severe misconception that is similar to Zeno's paradox of Achilles and the Tortoise:

Given a hydrogen atom we have (in principle) an infinite number of shells. However, the gap between the shells gets smaller and smaller. If you would jump from shell to shell, you'd eventually only absorb a finite amount of energy (just like in Zeno's paradox, after an infinite amount of time steps, only a finite amount of time has passed).

In math: The theoretical difference between two energy levels is given by $E=\approx -13.6(1/n^2-1/(n+1)^2)$, where $n$ is the number of the level. If you add all levels from the ground state $n=1$ to $n=\infty$, you get an energy of $-13.6$. That's exactly the ionization energy.

The second problem is a misconception how atomic transitions work:

In short, there is no reason for an electron to always jump to the next higher level. In fact, if you provide the energy for the electron to go from level $n=1$ to $n=x$ all at once, it can directly "jump" to that level (there are "forbidden transistions" if you include magnetic numbers or if you have superselection rules or whatever, but that's not the point here).

Comment: Didn't understand much

Comment: a) The sum of an infinite number of steps of energy doesn't necessarily mean infinite energy. b) An electron can jump many levels at once.